# javax.validation - validation context (for caching purpose)

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, validation

I am using Hibernate validators to run validation constraints defined by javax.validation API. Everything runs on the Spring 3.

I defined my custom constraints:

- @ProjectExists
- @ProjectActive
- @ProjectCommentable

and my custom validators that covers above constraints.

Now I would like to validate following DTO:

```
public class Comment {
  private String content;

  @ProjectExists
  @ProjectActive
  @ProjectCommentable
  private String projectName;
}
```

The problem is that each validator has to run database query, find project and do something with it.

I am looking for solution which allows to cache project that was found before. The best solution would be to share something like "validation context" between all validators, so that I could set Project to validation context.

Next problem is that after validation DTO is transformed to data model, so the "find project query" has to be called once again. It would be good to reuse cached project also here.